# Автозакрытие alert у Bootstrap 3 если он вызывается через php?

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Есть форма обратной связи с двумя alert об успешной отправке письма или ошибке. 
**Как сделать автозакрытие этого alert через определенное время?**

Нашел один пример автозакрытия, но я не могу его адаптировать в свой код. Указывал внизу страницы, не срабатывает.
https://codepen.io/CSWApps/pen/XJoLmN

Сложность в том, что эти alert формируются в mail.php отправке письма.
Можно ли прописать решение прямо в php файле или есть js скрипт для автозакрытия алертов , если они появляются на странице?

Вот код вызова этих alert

```html
$result = '';
  if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $result .= '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
   $result .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
    $result .= 'УСПЕШНО ОТПРАВЛЕНО!';
    $result .= '</div>';

    echo $result;
    die();
  }

  $result = '';
  $result .= '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
  $result .= '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
  $result .= 'ОШИБКА ОТПРАВКИ';
  $result .= '</div>';

  echo $result;
```

Comment: что мешает вам закинуть скрипт в ваш mail.php?

Comment: его также закинуть вместо html кода? указат теги script ?

Comment: можно так, для уверенности что не затрагиваете, другие алерты можете добавить кастомные классы в скрипт и верстку